# AWS Codebuild build stage shows nginx was installed but container doesn't have nginx

Tags: aws-codebuild

I'm new with AWS Codebuild and trying to deploy my docker application in EKS. On my Dockerfile I'm running RUN apk add nginx and build stage shows that it's being installed.

```
Step 6/24 : RUN apk add nginx
 ---> Running in cbd7a4e37bb7
(1/2) Installing pcre (8.44-r0)
(2/2) Installing nginx (1.18.0-r15)
Executing nginx-1.18.0-r15.pre-install
Executing nginx-1.18.0-r15.post-install
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r6.trigger
OK: 15 MiB in 34 packages
Removing intermediate container cbd7a4e37bb7
 ---> a890efd77e97
```

After the BUILD stage has been completed, I enter my EKS pod but didn't see any nginx under /etc

```
/etc # ls
ImageMagick-7         fstab                 issue                 my.cnf.d              periodic              securetty             sysctl.d
alpine-release        group                 logrotate.d           mysql                 php7                  services              terminfo
apk                   group-                modprobe.d            network               pkcs11                shadow                udhcpd.conf
ca-certificates       hostname              modules               openldap              profile               shadow-               wgetrc
ca-certificates.conf  hosts                 modules-load.d        opt                   profile.d             shells
conf.d                init.d                motd                  os-release            protocols             ssh
crontabs              inittab               mtab                  passwd                resolv.conf           ssl
fonts                 inputrc               my.cnf                passwd-               rsyncd.conf           sysctl.conf
```

I manually executed apk add nginx inside my pod and that's the only time nginx appeared under /etc

My AWS Codebuild is using the following configurations:

```
Managed image
OS: Amazon Linux 2
Runtime: Standard
Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
Image version: Always use the latest image for this runtime version
Privilaged: Enabled
```

Also,
I noticed that AWS Build doesn't execute the following COPY command in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/ (this works)
COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (this doesn't, probably because nginx didn't get installed on runtime)
COPY docker/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-d9 (this doen't work.. still a mystery)
```

I hope I was able to provide the full details. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    PHP_VERSION: 7.4
    APP_HOME: /var/www/html
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...test4
      - aws --version
      - docker --version
      - echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
      - export PHP_VERSION=$PHP_VERSION
      - REPOSITORY_URI=xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx-xxxxxxx-x.amazonaws.com/development-ecr
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=$CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER
#      - IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
  build:
    commands: 
      - echo "PHP Version is $PHP_VERSION"
      - echo "$APP_HOME" 
      - echo Running Docker compose..
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build --build-arg PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION} -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest test/
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo "Setting Environment Variables related to AWS CLI for Kube Config Setup"          
      - CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $EKS_KUBECTL_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name codebuild-kubectl --duration-seconds 900)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')"
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')"
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')"
      - export AWS_EXPIRATION=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.Expiration')
      # Setup kubectl with our EKS Cluster              
      - echo "Update Kube Config"      
      - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name $EKS_CLUSTER_NAME
      # Apply changes to our Application using kubectl
      - echo "Delete current deployment"
      - kubectl delete deployment dev-spectrum-app
      - sleep 10
      - echo "Apply changes to kube manifests"            
      - kubectl apply -f kube-yaml/
      - echo "Completed applying changes to Kubernetes Objects"           
pipeline for other stages
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"dev-spectrum","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - cat imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.4

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION:+${PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine   

ARG APP_HOME
 
RUN echo "CHECKING ARGS: $APP_HOME ${PHP_VERSION}"

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add nginx

# Install library extension
RUN apk add libpng libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev libxpm-dev

# Install MySql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

# PHP packages
RUN apk add libressl \
        ca-certificates \
        openssh-client \
        rsync \
        git \ 
        curl \
        wget \
        gzip \
        tar \
        patch \
        perl \
        pcre \
        imap \
        imagemagick \
        mariadb-client \
        build-base \
        autoconf \
        libtool \
        php7-dev \
        pcre-dev \
        imagemagick-dev \
        php7 \
        php7-fpm \
        php7-opcache \  
        php7-session \
        php7-dom \
        php7-xml \
        php7-xmlreader \
        php7-ctype \
        php7-ftp \ 
        php7-json \
        php7-posix \
        php7-curl \
        php7-pdo \
        php7-pdo_mysql \
        php7-sockets \
        php7-zlib \
        php7-mcrypt \
        php7-mysqli \
        php7-sqlite3 \
        php7-bz2 \
        php7-phar \
        php7-openssl \
        php7-posix \
        php7-zip \
        php7-calendar \
        php7-iconv \
        php7-imap \
        php7-soap \
        php7-dev \
        php7-pear \
        php7-redis \
        php7-mbstring \
        php7-xdebug \
        php7-exif \
        php7-xsl \
        php7-ldap \
        php7-bcmath \
        php7-memcached \
        php7-oauth \
        php7-apcu

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    ln -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

# Install Drush
RUN composer global require drush/drush && \
    composer global update

# Copy php.ini memory limit increase
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY docker/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
#COPY docker/nginx/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-d9

RUN echo ${APP_HOME} ${PHP_VERSION}

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN mkdir /run/nginx;

#Copy composer files
COPY  composer.json composer.lock ./

RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
RUN composer dump-autoload

RUN set -eux; \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
#    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-d9

EXPOSE 80 433
CMD ["nginx"]

#RUN nginx
#RUN php-fpm

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Hi there, it would be helpful to see your Dockerfile, if possible, as well as your buildspec.yml. Another approach would be to build the container the way you want it locally and push it up to ECR and then just deploy that or use that as the base image for building another image which you deploy.

Comment: Hi @jstewart379 thanks for your response. I have updated my post and included my buildspec.yml and Dockerfile. Thank you!

Comment: @jstewart379 this is getting weird. I tried to build the container in my local and verified that nginx is present inside the container. Then, I pushed the image from my local to the ECR and deployed it to my Kubernetes. When I looked inside my pod, nginx is no longer there. T_T

Comment: What you're doing in the Dockerfile and the buildspec.yml looks normal. I'm not to familiar with EKS deployments though. If I was troubleshooting this, I would strip down everything but nginx and verify it's installed. Make sure that nginx/conf.d directory is there and that /usr/sbin/nginx -C <config file> works. Also from nginx docs, looks like there are specific ways to set up nginx containers in EKS. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/amazon-web-services/ingress-controller-elastic-kubernetes-services/.